# Flutter - InkWell not working when changing 'onTap' method

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I am trying to use InkWell widget or RaisedButton so I can display a ripple effect when tapping on widget.

I have no issue when I set up the `onTap` parameter to `(){}`, no issue also if I do a simple `print` inside the function like this `(){print("hello");}`, but as soon as I call my custom function, the ink well does not appear anymore. I have tried `onTap: customFunction,` or even `onTap: (){customFunction();},` but it does not change anything.

My first thought was that the problem was coming from the fact that my function has an optional parameter :

```
void customFunction([dynamic parameter]){
}
```

So I tried to call it like this `onTap: (){customFunction(null);}` or even to create an other function just to call it with a null parameter, but nothing has worked, finally, I have removed the optionality and forced the value to null but again, nothing changed.

My function is calling `setState` but I do not see why it will change anything.

This is the widget I am using with InkWell :

```
Center(
  child: Ink(
    height: 120,
    width: 120,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
    child: InkWell(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
      onTap: (){_onItemIndexChanged(null);},
      splashColor: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(_totalAmountToString(widget.totalAmount),
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

and I has also tried the same with RaisedButton :

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 120,
    width: 120,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
    child: RaisedButton(
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      onPressed: (){_onItemIndexChanged(null);},
      elevation: 0,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      splashColor: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
      child: Text(_totalAmountToString(widget.totalAmount),
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

and finally this is my function :

```
_onItemIndexChanged(charts.SelectionModel model) {
    double newAngle;
    int index;
    double p = 0;
    if (model != null) {
      if (model.selectedDatum.isNotEmpty) {
        index = model.selectedDatum.first.series.data
            .indexOf(model.selectedDatum.first.datum);
        if (index == _selectedItemIndex) index = -1;
      } else {
        index = -1;
      }
    } else {
      index = _selectedItemIndex + 1 == widget.data.first.data.length
          ? -1
          : _selectedItemIndex + 1;
    }

    if (index != -1) {
      for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        p += widget.data.first.data.elementAt(i).price;
      }
      p += widget.data.first.data.elementAt(index).price / 2;
      newAngle = -2 * pi * (p / widget.totalAmount) + pi / 2;
    } else {
      newAngle = _defaultAngle;
    }

    double originAngle =
        _startAngle != null ? _startAngle.value : _defaultAngle;
    _startAngle = null;

    setState(() {
      _selectedItemIndex = index;
      _animationController.reset();
      _startAngle = Tween(begin: originAngle, end: newAngle).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
              parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));
    });

    _animationController.forward().orCancel;
  }
```

The function `_onItemIndexChange` is called and does its job, no issue here. And the only thing I have to do to make the Ink Well worked is to removed the call to `_onItemIndexChange` and replace it with `(){}`

Comment: change "onPressed: (){_onItemIndexChanged(null);},"  by "onPressed: _onItemIndexChanged(null),"

Comment: If I do this I have a cascade of error : ```E/flutter (27746): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: This ticker was canceled: Ticker(created by _DonutPieChartCardState#b7d94(lifecycle state: created))
E/flutter (27746): null```

Comment: It makes no sense, there is no difference between one and the other. It is difficult to verify your code because it has a lot of dependence on it that are not listed. but you will see that if you comment on its function and put only one print on it, it is being called.

Comment: The ontap is working, the problem is in the function

Comment: I think there is a difference. The first time I am giving a function without calling it and the second time I am giving a function and calling it. So the function is executed multiple time (each time the tree is rebuilt I think)

Comment: I am going to try to change my function and I will come back to you when it will be done. Thanks for your help. (sorry for all the dependencies)

Comment: The way you are calling your function is correct. @ClaudioCastro probably meant to say `() => _onItemIndexChanged(null)` but it won't matter. Try commenting out the `setState()` block in your `_onItemIndexChanged` function and see if the ripple effect shows?

Comment: @user1032613, the problem is coming from the call to ```setState``` in my function. If I comment it, I have no issues and the ripple effect shows, but if I de-comment it and comment what is inside, the ripple effect does not show.

Answer (score 0):

`onTap: customFunction`, `onTap: (){customFunction();}`, and `onTap: () => customFunction()` all perform the same. My initial impression was that maybe `setState()` builds the screen again before the ripple effect is rendered. However, I tested your repro locally but having `setState()` in a function called from `onTap` still renders the ripple animation.

[image: Demo]

I've added this snippet on the Flutter demo app

```dart
Center(
  child: Ink(
    height: 120,
    width: 120,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
    child: InkWell(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
      onTap: () => _incrementCounter(),
      splashColor: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Count: $_counter'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

The only part of your repro that I'm unable to run was the functions inside `_onItemIndexChanged`. Without a complete [repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it'll be difficult to identify the cause of the reported behavior. If removing the functions inside `setState()` renders the ripple animation, I suggest starting from there to check what might be causing the issue.